# Sublime text 3 - Change color of php tags

Tags: sublimetext3

Simple question but I can't figure it out.

I just can't find a guide to help with this.

How do I can the color of tags,variables, methods in Sublime text 3?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The harder way is to change the .sublime-theme file. Download an extension that might be easier. Try this link maybe as well https://scotch.io/bar-talk/the-complete-visual-guide-to-sublime-text-3-themes-color-schemes-and-cool-features